# Flutter - adding columns to dynamic tables

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm new to flutter and I'm still learning how to use it. I was wondering how one would go about adding columns to a table that auto generates rows. More specifically how do I add columns to this example from the flutter website:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  static const int numItems = 10;
  List<bool> selected = List<bool>.generate(numItems, (int index) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: DataTable(
        columns: const <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Number'),
          ),
        ],
        rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
          numItems,
          (int index) => DataRow(
            color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              // All rows will have the same selected color.
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.08);
              }
              // Even rows will have a grey color.
              if (index.isEven) {
                return Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3);
              }
              return null; // Use default value for other states and odd rows.
            }),
            cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(Text('Row $index'))],
            selected: selected[index],
            onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                selected[index] = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to edit it like a normal table but it just wouldn't lets me add another column like a normal data table.

Comment: add another ``DataColumn()`` widget to the ``columns`` property. What's the issue here?

Comment: ``columns: const <DataColumn>[ DataColumn(label: Text('Number'), DataColumn(label: Text('Name'), DataColumn(label: Text('Etc') ]),``